Visual Studio 2022 is not building and running the file I want it to run
I'm working on masm64 and I had another file before this one so Visual Studio thinks that I'm trying to run the old one and that one is deleted so it doesn't work. This is the code
.CODE


;           <------
;    mov <dest>, <src>
;
;    mov <register>, <memory>
;    mov <register>, <immediate value>
;    mov <register>, <register>
;    mov <memory>, <register>



Example PROC

    mov r8, 0                   ; clear
    mov r8b, 11h                ; move 8 bits
    mov r8w, 2222h              ; move 16 bits
    mov r8d, 33333333h          ; move 32 bits
    mov r8, 4444444444444444h   ; move 64 bits
    mov rax, r8                 ; move from register to register

    mov rax, 0                  ; clear
    mov al, 11h                 ; move into lower 8 bits of 16 bit register
    mov ah, 22h                 ; move into higher 8 bits of 16 bit register
    mov ax, 3333h               ; move 16 bits
    mov eax, 44444444h          ; move 32 bits
    mov rax, 5555555555555555h  ; move 64 bits

    mov r8, 0FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFh  ; initialize
    mov r8b, 11h                ; move 8 bits
    mov r8w, 2222h              ; move 16 bits
    mov r8d, 33333333h          ; !!! storing in the lower 32 bits will clear the top 32 bits !!!

    ret
Example ENDP

END

And this is the error:
Done building project "MASM64ONLY.vcxproj" -- FAILED.

Your file misses end at the end, but it sounds like you have problems outside of this file, with the project/configuration. Can you show the contents of the vcxproj file for example, maybe that helps

@user555045  I'll tell you what happened. I had another project in the same solution, so when I start without debugging, it directs to that deleted project and so it does not work. There is a end in my code but I forgot to include it the code snippet I provided.

@user555045 The error is Done building project "MASM64ONLY.vcxproj" -- FAILED.

This could be caused by cache files. I wonder if you have tried cleaning and rebuilding the solution or restarting VS.
